# Is there any tool by which i can check my query or performance of procedure in db2?

Tags: db2

There are many tools for SQL Server to analyse the performance of query or Stored Procedure and it's standarad. Is there any tool by which i can check my query or performance of procedure in IBM db2 9.7?

Comment: `db2batch` is a pretty powerful tool for benchmarking, and is included with the product.  See the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools for performance monitor:

- IBM® InfoSphere® Optim™ Performance Manager for DB2® for Linux, UNIX and Windows http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/performance-manager
- dbi brother-panther http://www.dbisoftware.com/brother-panther.php
- Dell Foglight for DB2 http://software.dell.com/products/foglight-for-db2/